# What is this "Error" in JMeter results?

Tags: jmeter

I'm currently testing performance on my website and I got these many errors:

[image: JMeter tree results]

FYI, my web app is using Zend Framework (so LAMP) with Nginx as reversed proxy.

Comment: Please, turn language to english. Show also request tab, raw response tab, unfolded scenario. I suppose exception is threw, so show also jmeter console output.

Answer (score 0):

Please look into jmeter.log (%JMETER_HOME%/bin/jmeter.log) for error details.